# .htaccess redirect https://www to non www for wildcard subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, https, no-www

I am using htaccess to force https for all subdomains and removing www. This is working except for when someone manually adds https://www. - then we get a security error. How can I force https://www. to use the non www url?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'problem' was with the cert and not the redirects.

Per PLESK support
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000067665-Wildcard-SSL-on-a-subdomain-is-not-working-with-www-prefix